# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' - error while trying to webscrap through table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wanted to make a program that would webscrap through my lesson plan, but i keep getting the same error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

with open ('o24.html','r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('tabele', class_='tabela')
    header =[]
    rows = []
    for i, row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
        if i == 0:
            header = [el.text.strip() for el in row.find_all('th')]
        else:
            rows.append([el.text.strip() for el in row.find_all('td')])
    print(header)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

First i thought it was a problem with requests module, but after checking and reinstalling everything seems fine

Here is the html code:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" class="tabela">
<tr>
<th>Nr</th>
<th>Godz</th>
<th>Poniedziałek</th>
<th>Wtorek</th>
<th>Środa</th>
<th>Czwartek</th>
<th>Piątek</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="nr">1</td>
<td class="g"> 8:00- 8:45</td>
<td class="l"><span style="font-size:85%"><span class="p">prog. apl in-1/2</span> <span class="n">ŻP</span> <a href="s4.html" class="s">9</a></span></td>
<td class="l">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="l"><span style="font-size:85%"><span class="p">j.ang.zaw.in-1/2</span> <span class="n">JK</span> <a href="s23.html" class="s">40</a></span></td>
<td class="l"><span style="font-size:85%"><span class="p">adm.b.d.-1/2</span> <span class="n">ŻP</span> <a href="s4.html" class="s">9</a></span></td>
<td class="l"><span class="p">matematyka</span> <span class="n">CA</span> <a href="s34.html" class="s">51</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="nr">2</td>
<td class="g"> 8:50- 9:35</td>
<td class="l"><span style="font-size:85%"><span class="p">prog. apl in-1/2</span> <span class="n">ŻP</span> <a href="s4.html" class="s">9</a></span><br><span style="font-size:85%"><span class="p">j.ang.zaw.in-2/2</span> <span class="n">MK</span> <a href="s33.html" class="s">50</a></span></td>
<td class="l"><span class="p">biologia</span> <span class="n">HK</span> <a href="s27.html" class="s">44</a></td>
<td class="l"><span class="p">religia</span> <span class="n">BE</span> <a href="s9.html" class="s">16</a></td>
<td class="l"><span style="font-size:85%"><span class="p">adm.b.d.-1/2</span> <span class="n">ŻP</span> <a href="s4.html" class="s">9</a></span><br><span style="font-size:85%"><span class="p">j.angielski-2/2</span> <span class="n">RD</span> <a href="s15.html" class="s">25</a></span></td>
<td class="l"><span class="p">matematyka</span> <span class="n">CA</span> <a href="s34.html" class="s">51</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
scrappings\scrap.py", line 11, in <module>
    for i, row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error.

Comment: `soup.find` found nothing and returned `None`. Subsequently calling `table.find_all` is trying to call `None.find_all`. the `None` object doesn't have a `find_all` method which raises the `AttributeError`

Comment: Hey welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you update your post to include the HTML you are trying to find with `soup.find('tabele', class_='tabela')`?

Comment: This looks like a misspelling as suggested by @Übermensch. Try `table = soup.find('table', class_='tabela')` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a typo, you should correct it as follows:

```
table = soup.find('table', class_='tabela')
```